# What is the best back up for databases in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure

I have a number of databases in Azure that I want to back up in AWS, what is the best type of storage for databases in AWS ?
Can this be automated in Azure ?

Comment: Why not use something from azure itself.? Snapshots and backups done done and stored in azure will be easier and faster to restore too.

Comment: I have already in Azure , I want offline storage as well.

Comment: What are your reasons for wanting "offline storage"?

Comment: needing extra security

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the 'old days' before Cloud Computing, back-up typically involved sending data to a secondary *disaster recovery* location where there was (typically inadequate) backup equipment that could takeover the activities of the primary data center.

These days, Cloud Computing provides such as AWS and Azure **run multiple data centers in the one region**. A 'Region' contains multiple 'Availability Zones', each of which is a separate data center.

Also, many services (eg Amazon S3, Azure Blob storage) are **'regional' services that automatically run across multiple Availability Zones**. This means that a failure in one AZ does not impact operation or availability of the service. However, individual virtual machines (eg Amazon EC2, Azure VMs) run on single hosts, so each one operates in only a single AZ.

Thus, rather than attempting to copy data to a "different location" or a different cloud service, it is better to **take advantage of the backup capabilities offered by the cloud provider**.

From [Automatic, geo-redundant backups - Azure SQL Database | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/automated-backups-overview?view=azuresql):

> By default, Azure SQL Database stores backups in geo-redundant storage blobs that are replicated to a paired region. Geo-redundancy helps protect against outages that affect backup storage in the primary region. It also allows you to restore your databases in a different region in the event of a regional outage.
>
> The storage redundancy mechanism stores multiple copies of your data so that it's protected from planned and unplanned events. These events might include transient hardware failure, network or power outages, or massive natural disasters.

This would not only meet your requirement for backing up data to another location, but it also makes it **quick and easy to restore data** when necessary. Compare that to sending data to a different cloud provider, where *you* would be responsible for converting file formats, launching replacement services and loading data from backup. That type of thing really isn't necessary if you are using a managed database service.

Backing-up data is easy. Restoring is hard!

**Bottom line:** Use a managed database (eg Azure SQL Database) and use the managed backup options they provide. They will give you the redundancy you seek, while making the process *MUCH* easier to manage.

Comment: thankyou so much that answered everything. I will look at this approach

Comment: Just a thought on this , what if the user has been compromised and cant login to azure

Comment: Just a question,. What if the subscription has been compromised and no company user can login to azure ? That will require resetting everything backup again. At least i have the dbs offsite and can re-create.

Comment: Good security practice is to use Multi-Factor Authentication on your login, so that it cannot be compromised.

Comment: Please note that restoring your database to operating performance involves much more than having a backup of the data. You'll also need to consider **where** to restore the data, the **format** of the backup and the ability to **restore** the data. Also, databases do not operate on their own -- you would presumably have **applications** that use the database, so it would be important to run them as High Availability. It's not easy to "re-create" a system -- much better to design a system that can handle failure (eg using regional services) without resorting to "re-creating" resources.

Comment: the applications are already backed up and I have managed to make restoring quite a quick process; namely as long as it takes to deploy to Azure. The only factor is the database. Yes i do understand what you are saying , but I am looking at worst case scenario, storing somewhere different to my Cloud Provider.

Comment: Another option I was thinking was to backup to a bacpac file on a local machine . I have done that before and found restoring to be quite quick . What are your thoughts on this approach ?